# Can I get elements from column of lists by list of indexes?

Tags: python, python-polars

In (Py)Polars there is method of subset list elements in column of lists according to list of indexes in other column? I.e. `arr.get()` accepts only Integer and not accept Expressions (like `pl.col('prices').arr.get(pl.col('idxs').arr.first())`) ?

Can I get some like:

```
df = pl.DataFrame(
{'idxs': [[0], [1], [0, 2]], 
 'prices': [[0.0, 3.5], [4.6, 0.0], [0.0, 7.8, 0.0]]}
)

(df
  .with_column(
       pl.col('prices').arr.get(pl.col('idxs')).alias('zero_prices') 

)
)
```

### Can be resolved with apply UDF python function to `pl.struct(pl.all())`

Like

```
def get_zero_prices(cols):
    return [float(el) for i, el in enumerate(cols['prices']) if I in cols['idxs']]

(df
  .with_column(
       pl.struct(pl.all()).apply(lambda x: get_zero_prices(x)).alias('zero_prices') 

)
)
```

But this looks not so ideomatic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is to be able to utilize the full expression API whilst operating on certain sub-elements or groups. That's what a groupby is!

So ideally we groom our `DataFrame` in a state where very group corresponds to the elements of our lists.

First we start with some data and and then we add a `row_idx` that will represent out unique groups.

```py
df = pl.DataFrame({
 "idx": [[0], [1], [0, 2]], 
 "array": [["a", "b"], ["c", "d"], ["e", "f", "g"]]
}).with_row_count("row_nr")
print(df)
```

```
shape: (3, 3)
┌────────┬───────────┬─────────────────┐
│ row_nr ┆ idx       ┆ array           │
│ ---    ┆ ---       ┆ ---             │
│ u32    ┆ list[i64] ┆ list[str]       │
╞════════╪═══════════╪═════════════════╡
│ 0      ┆ [0]       ┆ ["a", "b"]      │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 1      ┆ [1]       ┆ ["c", "d"]      │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2      ┆ [0, 2]    ┆ ["e", "f", "g"] │
└────────┴───────────┴─────────────────┘
```

Next we `explode` by the `"idx"` column so that we can we create the groups for our groupby.

```py
df = df.explode("idx")
print(df)
```

```
shape: (4, 3)
┌────────┬─────┬─────────────────┐
│ row_nr ┆ idx ┆ array           │
│ ---    ┆ --- ┆ ---             │
│ u32    ┆ i64 ┆ list[str]       │
╞════════╪═════╪═════════════════╡
│ 0      ┆ 0   ┆ ["a", "b"]      │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 1      ┆ 1   ┆ ["c", "d"]      │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2      ┆ 0   ┆ ["e", "f", "g"] │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2      ┆ 2   ┆ ["e", "f", "g"] │
└────────┴─────┴─────────────────┘
```

Finally we can apply the `groupby` and take the subelements for each list/group.

```py
(df
 .groupby("row_nr")
 .agg([
     pl.col("array").first(),
     pl.col("idx"),
     pl.col("array").first().take(pl.col("idx")).alias("arr_taken")
 ])
)
```

This returns:

```
shape: (3, 4)
┌────────┬─────────────────┬───────────┬────────────┐
│ row_nr ┆ array           ┆ idx       ┆ arr_taken  │
│ ---    ┆ ---             ┆ ---       ┆ ---        │
│ u32    ┆ list[str]       ┆ list[i64] ┆ list[str]  │
╞════════╪═════════════════╪═══════════╪════════════╡
│ 0      ┆ ["a", "b"]      ┆ [0]       ┆ ["a"]      │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 1      ┆ ["c", "d"]      ┆ [1]       ┆ ["d"]      │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2      ┆ ["e", "f", "g"] ┆ [0, 2]    ┆ ["e", "g"] │
└────────┴─────────────────┴───────────┴────────────┘
```

Answer (score 0):

It's an old question, but you can do this now directly with the listNameSpace expression `take`:

```py
df.with_columns(pl.col('array').list.take(pl.col('idx')))

shape: (3, 3)
┌────────┬───────────┬────────────┐
│ row_nr ┆ idx       ┆ array      │
│ ---    ┆ ---       ┆ ---        │
│ u32    ┆ list[i64] ┆ list[str]  │
╞════════╪═══════════╪════════════╡
│ 0      ┆ [0]       ┆ ["a"]      │
│ 1      ┆ [1]       ┆ ["d"]      │
│ 2      ┆ [0, 2]    ┆ ["e", "g"] │
└────────┴───────────┴────────────┘
```

Comment: And further changed to `gather` since 0.19.14